# JUnit Test for Java

Tags: java, junit

How can I write a JUnit test for below method?

```
private static final String CHAR_LIST = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

    private int getRandNum() {
         Random getRand = new Random();
         int randomNum = getRand.nextInt(CHAR_LIST.length());
         if (randomNum == 0) {
              return randomNum;
         } else {
              return randomNum - 1;
         }
    }
```

Comment: What about it do you want to test?

Comment: `randomNum - 1 == -1` is the same as `randomNum == 0`.

Comment: run a hundred times, check that you never get 0 as result

Comment: Use a search engine of your choice to search for a JUnit tutorial then.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a decent question imo..

Comment: @Tobb no, it's not. It doesn't show any research effort, and it's simply answered by reading a tutorial.

Comment: Not the way I saw it, but from discussing with the OP it seems correct. But it _could_ have been a question regarding testing stuff with the `Random` class involved (because that is quite tricky.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to create a 100% meaningful test here, but I think you should decompose your method a little, so you can mock the `Random` object.

But first off, you should simplify your method. If I understand correctly, what you want here is to generate a random index for your list, but the way you are doing it you will never generate the last index in the list, and the possibility for getting the first index (0) is twice that of getting any of the other indices.

```
//either this:
private Random random = new Random();
//or this:
Random createRandom() {
    return new Random();
}

private int getRandNum() {
    //either this:
    return random.nextInt(CHAR_LIST.size());
    //or this:
    return createRandom().nextInt(CHAR_LIST.size());
}
```

Then, you can replace the Random object with a mock/spy, either through reflection, or by spying:

```
public class MyClassTest {
    private MyClass myClass;
    private Random mockedRandom;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        myClass = spy(new MyClass());
        mockedRandom = mock(Random.class);
        when(myClass.createRandom()).thenReturn(mockedRandom);
    }

    @Test
    public void getRandNumShouldGenerateAValidIndexForCHAR_LIST() {
        //Given CHAR_LIST.size() = 5
        when(mockedRandom.nextInt(5)).thenReturn(2);

        final int randomNumber = myClass.getRandNum();

        assertEquals(2, randomNumber);
        verify(mockedRandom).nextInt(5);
   }

   //a "black box" approach:
   @Test
   public void blackboxish() {
      //Make sure CHAR_LIST.size() = 3
      when(myClass.createRandom()).thenReturn(new Random());
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          final int random = myClass.getRandNum();
          assertTrue(random >= 0);
          assertTrue(random < 3);
      }
   } //there is a theoritical possibility of a false positive here, but it's small..
```

Comment: What is MyClass, mock, when, and verify? I get errors for those

Comment: MyClass is the name of your class. mock/when/verify are Mockito methods, Mockito (or some other mock framework) is a really useful for making unit tests.